# How to use json_decode in view blade.

Tags: php, laravel, xpath, domparser

How to use json_decode on in the table of link part. 
Trying to use it but I am missing something. 
when I try to push in foreach section laravel error page pops up. like this.

Undefined variable: link (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

```
<table id="myTable2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>会社名</th>
      <th>物件名</th>
      <th>所在地</th>
      <th>販売価額</th>
      <th>総戸数</th>
      <th>間取り</th>
      <th>専有面積</th>
      <th>バルコニー面積</th>
      <th>竣工年月日</th>
      <th>入居年月日</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
   @foreach($estates as $estate)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$estate->company_name}}</td>

      $links = json_decode($estate->link); 
      foreach($links as $link){
      <td><a href="{{$link}}" } target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a></td>

      <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->hows_old}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->balcon_m2}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
<table/>
```

Any help? Thank you?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the collation settings for the company_name to utf8_general_ci in your table structure.

Try this to get all links for the current loaded html, you need to place this code before $changeForMyDB :

```
   $all_links = [];
    $allPTags = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($allPTags as $atag){
        $all_links[] = $atag->getAttribute('href');
    }
```

change your 'links'=>json_encode($all_links)

Edit: to display links

```
<?php
  $links = json_decode($estate->link); 
  $hrefs = "";
  foreach($links as $link){
    $hrefs .= '<a href="'.$link.'" } target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a><br/>';
  }
  $hrefs .= "";
?>
```

> Blockquote

```
<td>{{$hrefs}}</td> <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>  
   <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>   <td>{{$estate->hows_old}}</td>  
   <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>   <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>  
   <td>{{$estate->balcon_m2}}</td>   <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>  
   <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
```

Comment: my table collation is utf8_unicode_ci and with this no problem with japanese words. Always that way. I think, problem must be different reason.

Comment: In your 'link' => $outlineUrls, do you mean $outlineUrl this variable? because you are trying to save the whole url array.

Comment: oh, actually i want to save that $outlineUrl one at a time. it contains a couple of links that s why I want to save it for each page table column one at a time. becouse after that I going to use it as link for each page I scraped.

Comment: How can I do that? where exactly do I need to do that? In here like this:  `'link' => json_encode($outlineUrls),`

Comment: Yup just like that

Comment: thanks for that, but this I've got taking error like this. `Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'remote_id' at row 1` oh man, errors are not finishing...

Comment: Change your field type for remote_id to varchar.

Comment: thanks for that too, it fix that error but still there a problem with the $outlineUrl, json turn it a string and made this error  ` String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'link' at row 1 ` I think the problem is here how can I insert those links to database for each column. Any idea for that?

Comment: Try to change the link field type into text or long text :D

Comment: haha okay mate! I take the smootly! but last problem continious just take the first link of the array. I want all the link for each,

Comment: See the code to get all links in my answer. I edited it.

Comment: Oh yes, that s very nice touch there links are changing but one problem links coming are this. http://localhost/`[%22https:////www.31sumai.com//pid//about//%22,%22https:////www.31sumai.com//%22,%22https:////www.kyotoshimogyo93.com//shinchiku//K1703001//%22,%22https:////www.kyotoshimogyo93.com//shinchiku//K1703001//%22,%22?` over and over and over :)

Comment: when you the links from your database, you need to use json_decode and use the foreach to iterate it.

Comment: I tried it like this in view blade:  <td><a href="{{$estate->json_decode(link)}}" but already laravel's error page pops up.

Comment: $links = json_decode($estate->link); foreach($links as $link){<td><a href="{{$link}}"}

Comment: I update my quesiton. check the question! I insert my view blade there. I couldn't manage to enter json_decode there. could you edit it? You really helping me out.

Comment: if I put your codes like that my link column are gone void. I think it s becouse laravel. How to change it for laravel